# Why can't I establish a TCP/IP connection between my PC and a friend's PC with windows sockets? (Connection Timed Out)

Tags: tcp, ip, winsock

So, I've been working for about 1 week and I can't establish the connection, I tried in languages like C++ and C# (I'm focused on doing it in C#) but in neither of the 2 worked.

First of all, when making or downloading these programs there is an alert: "Windows Firewall protect" but I press the Accept button. I tried all the IPv4 addresses that appeared when you type "ipconfig" in the command prompt but only with 1 of them I could make connection (which only worked on my own computer) and with the other one it doesn't even let me make the connection. I also tried with the ip that web pages give you (https://www.whatismyip.com, https://www.cual-es-mi-ip.net) but it did not work either.

When making the connection I first start the server with my friend's computer (which also accepts the Windows Firewall) and then with the same ip and port with which my friend started the server (not 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0) but after a while I get the error 10060 or something related to connection timed out (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2).

Note: All these programs are "chats".

Comment: Port forwarding on the router for the server? There's no actual code for us to help you with here, so it doesn't really seem like a programming question?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I'm not really looking for help in the code of my programs per se, I consider that what is wrong is when I try to connect.
Also I think that the best thing would be that someone explains me well what is happening to be able to apply it to my code.

Comment: With TCP, one computer will have software that acts as a server (listening) and the other will have software that acts as the client (connects). Common things that get in the way are either a firewall on one of the computers, or the firewall on the router. In the case of the router, it doesn't know that it needs to the let the traffic in for the server application. Some applications (e.g. games) get around this by using NAT to automatically punch a hole in the firewall, but often you'll have to do this manually on the router config page. It will be under "Port Forwarding" or similar.

Comment: Note that you should be using your public IP if the client isn't on the same network. For example, 192.168.0.5 means something different to your router compared to your friends. If you type "what is my ip address?" into Google, it will show you your public IP.

Comment: Are you using [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4) or [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)? When using IPv4, it could be that your [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) is not giving you your own IP address, so that you must share the same IPv4 address with several other customers. This happens often because IPv4 addresses are scarce. In that case, even port forwarding will probably not help, so that you cannot act as a server with IPv4.

Comment: _"I'm **not really looking for help** in the **code of my programs** per se... I think that the best thing would be that someone explains me well what is happening **to be able to apply it to my code**"_ - well you can't have it both ways.  Also, if that's the case why tag your post `c#`?  Stack Overflow is for helping with code **not** network infrastructure.   You haven't even mentioned what _port_ you are using.  Most likely it is being blocked.  Either open up the port or use `80`.  And use https://whatismyipaddress.com/